# How can i search for autosys job owner through unix

Tags: unix, jobs, owner, autosys

I need a command to search for specific owner in autosys job. Either of the way, if my search string may check in entire jil code or related for a specific field.

Please let me know the command, which is useful for this....

Thanks,
Rk

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for.  If you want a list of all jobs which are run against a specific owner try the following:

autorep -J ALL -q | egrep "ownername" -b5 | egrep "insert_job" | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq

where the word 'ownername' should be replaced with the owner you're looking for.  If you want to check boxes as well you may want to change the awk statement to awk '{print $2 $3}' just in case.

Of course if you have access you can probably run a zql query against the database.

Hope this helps!